# How to split char Array in chunks which is a new array (Java 8)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split, iterator

I want to split a char array for each entered char c in my method and for each entered c it should split the char array, remove the entered c and create new chunks of arrays in a new array. So from:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r',
'l', 'd', '!']
```

with calling `split("l")` method it should print:

```
[['H', 'e'], ['o', ' ',
'W', 'o', 'r'], ['d', '!']]

public MyString[] split(char c) {
    MyString[] newarr = new MyString[c];
    ArrayList<MyString> arrlst = new ArrayList<MyString>();

    for (MyString ch : arrlst) {
        for (int k = 0; k < arrlst.size(); k++) {
            arrlst.spliterator();
        }
    }

    MyString[] newarr2 = new MyString[c];
    return newarr;
}
```

I know it doesn't make sense yet, I'm trying to figure out what I was trying to do last night. The plan ist to fill arrlst, which is an arraylist of type of MyString which objects of MyString.

MyString[] is defined as following:

```
public class MyString {

    private char[] arr;

    public MyString(int length) {


        arr = new char[length]; 

    }
```

With MyString I want to implement a String class similiar to String in Java. (I also defined some exceptions I didn't list here though, would be a long code.)

Comment: Your code makes little sense and we have no idea what MyString is. Maybe have another go before posting a question, you should be able to get further than your current attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done in Single Scary(Very) line, if existing utilities are allowed to use.

```
char[] chars = new char[]{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'};
String[][] processedData = Arrays.stream(new String(chars).split("l")).map(x-> Arrays.stream(x.split("")).filter(y->!y.equalsIgnoreCase("")).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[]{})).filter(x->x.length!=0).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[][]{});
```

**Updated Based on the comment:**

I have implemented a custom string class with `toString()` & `split()` method replicating the original String class behavior.

Here is the piece of code from it. I hope this is what you are expecting,

```
public MyString[] split(char c){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<MyString> myStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < characterSequence.length; i++){
            if(characterSequence[i] != c){
                builder.append(characterSequence[i]);
            }
            else{
                if(builder.length() != 0){
                    myStringList.add(new MyString(builder.toString()));
                    builder = new StringBuilder();
                }
            }
        }
        if(builder.length() != 0){
            myStringList.add(new MyString(builder.toString()));
        }
        return myStringList.toArray(new MyString[]{});
    }
```

This is how it works,

```
char[] chars = new char[]{'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d','!'};
MyString myString = new MyString(chars);// or new MyString("Hello World!"); 
MyString[] splitData = myString.split('l'); 
MyString.print(splitData);// Prints [[H,e],[o, ,W,o,r],[d,!]]
```

For complete implementation, have a look at this [Repo](https://github.com/NeotericDev/PublicCodeSamples/tree/master/ReplicatingCustomString/src/com/company)

Comment: Thanks for the response, L! Does this work for characters in an array? I suppose not, because your array ist String[][], while my MyString[] stores characters. But I haven't thought of two dimensional arrays, though, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Is there no method for this with only for loops, or do I need arraylists, streams,..? What would be the easiest and cleanest method, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Yeah, it’s completely possible with normal loops. Will update answer in a moment. Got into middle of something. In the mean time, can you show what is `MyString[]`?

Comment: @Light By the way, I used streams only because, specifically you mentioned Java8 in your question.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I updated my post. Streams would be possible as well, I'm curious if my idea with for loops would work though, i have no idea how. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Light Yagami! What a coincidence.. i didn't noticed your name and profile picture at all.. Here I have updated the code with link for working complete implementation

Comment: Thank you for you implementation, it helped me out alot. You really put some work in this, L.

Comment: @Light Happy to hear that it was useful :)